# Quiver plot without arrow stem

Tags: matlab, plot, customization, visualization, matlab-figure

I am simulating the motion of particles in MATLAB. I am using `quiver` to be able to get the direction of their motion. However, I would like to have only the arrowhead without the stem. I am unable to achieve this.

I tried using the following,

```
quiver(x,y,vx,vy,'LineStyle','none','ShowArrowHead','on')
```

to get rid of the stem, but the arrowhead too does not show up. Is there a way around this?

Answer (score 2):

`'LineStyle','none'` didn't work because the style applies both to the stem and to the head, so setting it to `none` hides both.

This can be solved by digging around some undocumented properties of the `Quiver` object. Exploring the properties of a `Quiver` object (using `struct(<handle to quiver plot>)`) we can see that a quiver plot has `NodeChildren` property, and that it is made of 4 elements,

```matlab
>> hq = quiver(x,y,u,v);
>> hq.NodeChildren
ans = 
  4×1 graphics array:

  ListOfPointsHighlight
  LineStrip
  LineStrip
  Marker
```

The `LineStrip` objects you see above, correspond, from top to bottom, to tails and the heads. From here it's just a matter of hiding the tails via their `Visible` property:

```matlab
[x,y] = meshgrid(0:0.2:2,0:0.2:2);
u = cos(x).*y;
v = sin(x).*y;

figure();
hq = quiver(x,y,u,v);

pause(0.1); % this appears to help
hq.NodeChildren(2).Visible = 'off';
```

Resulting in:

[image]

Tested on R2019a.

Answer (score 0):

In this case, quiver will plot the arrows offset from the datapoints, where they would normally occur on the end of the arrow stem.
It is difficult to control the stem-length to the head size, plot closed arrowheads, or modify the shape and location of the quiver arrows using MATLAB's quiver() command.

An alternative is the file-exchange arrow3() function, which is available here:

https://www.mathworks.com/matlabcentral/fileexchange/14056-arrow3

The arrow3() function has many examples here:

https://kr.mathworks.com/matlabcentral/mlc-downloads/downloads/submissions/14056/versions/16/previews/arrow3_examples.html

An example using the code for  the quiver() function with arrow3() instead

```
[x,y] = meshgrid(0:0.2:2,0:0.2:2);
u = cos(x).*y;
v = sin(x).*y;

figure();
%hq = quiver(x,y,u,v);
p1 = [x(:) y(:)]; % data start point
u = u(:); v=v(:);
arrow3(p1,p1+0.01*[u,v],'k',1,2); % create small (0.01) arrow stems
```