# Change Arrowhead size in quiver plot OCTAVE

Tags: matlab, octave

I am making a simple quiver plot, but due to arrowhead size depending on the length of arrows, The arrowheads become so small that the arrow is not practically visible. I want to scale up the arrowheads to one universal size (all arrows should have the same arrowhead size in this quiver plot.

```
A=5;

[X,Y] = meshgrid(-3:0.5:3,-3:0.5:3);

U = A*(X.^2-Y.^2)./((X.^2+Y.^2).^2);
V = (2*A*X.*Y)./((X.^2+Y.^2).^2);

figure(1)
h = quiver(X,Y,U,V,10);
set(h,'MaxHeadSize',0.1,'AutoScale','on', 'AutoScaleFactor', 2)
```

This is how my plot looks:

[image: current plot]

This is how the Arrowheads should look like in size

[image: plot]

Comment: I don't think this is an option, you can scale the arrows to be a consistent size by dividing `U` and `V` by the norm of the arrows (`sqrt(U.^2+V.^2)`) but the stems of the arrows are always drawn by `quiver`.

Comment: For hiding stems, read this: [Quiver plot without arrow stem](https://stackoverflow.com/q/56642439/5698672)

Comment: Thank you for this answer!! I was in desperate need of some response.